# GHCi Sourcing Bash Files?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Suppose you have `bash_function` defined in `/path/to/script.sh`, and you'd like to use this GHCi quickly. The following doesn't work:

```
Prelude> :!source /path/to/script.sh
Prelude> :!bash_function
```

Is there a way to load a GHCi's bash state so that you can execute non-stock shell functions?

Answer (score 4):

You can't keep the state around, but you can do this:

```
:!source /path/to/script.sh && bash_function
```

If there's a particular script you use a lot, you could add a command to your `~/.ghci` to make this more convenient; for example

```
:def fun Prelude.return Prelude.. (":!source /path/to/script.sh && "Prelude.++)
```

would enable you to use this in ghci instead:

```
:fun bash_function
```